# android submenu shows without creating it

Tags: android, android-menu

I Have the following menu, 
  When I run it it show an icon for submenu which is appears empty.
  If I remove the first Item

the submenu item disappear. I don't understand why this happens and how to remove the submenu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/mtitle"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout"
    android:title="T"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/mlogout"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout"
    android:title=""
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/mchange_password"
    android:icon="@drawable/change_password"
    android:title=""
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/mgpson"
    android:icon="@drawable/gps_off"
    android:title=""
    android:enabled="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/mgrpson"
    android:icon="@drawable/gprs_off"
    android:title=""
    android:enabled="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
<item android:id="@+id/mstatusConnection"
    android:icon="@drawable/disconnected"
    android:title=""
    android:enabled="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: why enabled = false? And what does showing without creating means?

Comment: I don't have enough point to Post an image, But a submenu icon appears at the left side, where if you open it it's empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is empty because the title is empty :-)

Just try this

```
android:title="Title of your choice"
```

for every menu item.

Your current menu item is

```
<item android:id="@+id/mgpson"
    android:icon="@drawable/gps_off"
    android:title=""
    android:enabled="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

You need to have

```
<item android:id="@+id/mgpson"
    android:icon="@drawable/gps_off"
    android:title="Title of your choice"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Hope this is clear